# Using Linear Gradient for headerBackground

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm just starting with react native so my apologies for the dumb question.

Trying the change the header colour and add a gradient, not sure what I'm doing wrong. 
Everything compiles but header stays white.

```
  const defaultHeaderOptions = {
  headerBackground: <LinearGradient
          start={{x: -0.01,y: 0.51,}}
          end={{x: 1.01,y: 0.49,}}
          locations={[0, 1]}
          colors={['black', "rgb(139, 27, 140)"]}
          style={{ flex: 0 }}/>,
          headerTintColor: 'black',
          headerLargeTitle: true,}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are working with react-navigation v5, `headerBackground` has to be a function:

```js
headerBackground: () => <LinearGradient {...your props} />,
```

see the [docs on headerBackground](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator#headerbackground)

Answer (score 0):

I use expo-router and tamagui elements

```
      <Stack.Screen
        name="records/[id]"
        options={{
          animation: 'slide_from_right',
          presentation: 'fullScreenModal',
          headerBackground: () => (<LinearGradient
            position="absolute"
            left={0}
            right={0}
            bottom={-250} // so it doesn't leave any stitches 
            top={0}
            colors={[theme.leftColor.val, theme.rightColor.val]}
            start={[1, 0]}
            end={[0, 1]}
          />)
        }}
      />
```